# Qt Gui private and xcb_visualid_t

Tags: linux, qt

Using QPA form Qt gui private parts, we can query things like XCB connection. But is there a way to get xcb_visualid_t from Qt somehow?

Comment: Have you tried to do anything with `QWindow::winId()`?

Comment: Not really. I can get xcb_window_t from it. Can this xcb_visualid_t be somehow queried form a window? I don't know much about XCB internals.